# Page starts in the middle of the header

Tags: header-footer

The text on any of my pages starts right where the header is. So in the following document the section, which is the first text of the paper, will be right where the header is. Has anyone experienced this issue, or can explain why it happens?

My document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{color, colortbl} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{LastPage}
\lstset{language=Matlab}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{XX\\
XX
}
\rhead{XX\\
\today}

\begin{document}
%\hspace{1cm}
\section*{Bla bla bla}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please shorten your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) illustrating your problem.

Comment: My apologise, shortening the MWE actually also found the culprit for me. The fullpage package screws things up. So i just removed the fullpage package and manually changed the margins.

Comment: TeX complains `Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):
Make it at least 25.16252pt` or essentially the redefine the headheight to suite your needs. This is so because you are creating new lines in the header.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue resolved by the OP in the process of constructing a MWE.

Comment: I've closed here as the resolution is 'building an example', which is unlikely to help future visitors.